# Uniqueness of weak limit in $H_0^1({\Omega})$ and strong limit in $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a bounded sequence in $H_0^1({\Omega})$ for some $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ (which is "appropriate" for the following theorems).
Since $H_0^1({\Omega})$ is compactly embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$ by the Rellich-Kondrashev theorem, there exists a subsequence that converges strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$.
$H_0^1({\Omega})$ is also reflexive so by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem there also exists a subsequence that converges weakly in $H_0^1({\Omega})$.

**Why should these two subsequences have the same limit?**
I would say that since $H_0^1({\Omega})\subset L^2(\Omega)$ we have $L^2(\Omega)^*\subset H_0^1({\Omega})^*$ so weak convergence in $H_0^1({\Omega})$ implies weak convergence in $L^2(\Omega)$, and the weak and strong limit must coincide.
But **what tells me that the two subsequences, to begin with, are the same?** After all those two theorems prove that there *exists* a subsequence such that..., so they may be as well be two different subsequences.
I think I *have to go deeper* and take a further subsequence of the subsequences, but I don't know how to formalize it without making a mess.

**Note**: I used $H_0^1({\Omega})$ and $L^2(\Omega)$ as an example but the same reasoning applies to any two Sobolev spaces connected by the Rellich-Kondrashev theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot infer that the subsequences have the same limit,
e.g., choose any $u \in H_0^1(\Omega) \setminus \{0\}$ and consider
$$u_n = (-1)^n \, u$$.

Then, $\{u_{2n}\}$ converges strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $\{u_{2n+1}\}$ converges weakly in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and the limits are different.

However, any subsequence which converges strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ converges weakly in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and vice versa.
This can be seen by a subsequence-subsequence argument.